# Test that method is called with proper parameters all across the software

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, methods, parameters

I've just ran into a problem recently when a method in my service was called with wrong parameters. This caused some kind of outage, so I'm thinking about how to prevent that in the future.

So assuming that I have the following method:

```
public boolean doSomething(String param1, String param2);
```

I want to verify that each time this method is called (no matter where in my service), the `param1` value is specific (e.g. only `String1`, `String2` and `String3` would be a valid parameter value for that.

Is there any technology/library/tool for that to verify this for instance in a unit test?

**Update:** as the accepted answer suggests, this is something that should not be covered through unit tests since unit tests are for behavioural testing. What would prevent the wrong call in the future is using `Preconditions` or just simple parameter check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible you should leverage **compile-time checks** rather than deferring the tests to runtime. If there are only three legal values then perhaps `param1` should be an `enum` rather than a `String`.

Unit tests are for verifying that a method *behaves* in a certain way. They treat the method like a black box and poke it from the outside. They don't help if you're concerned with how it is *called*. There you're inside the method and want to verify that the outside world is well-behaved. The way to do that is with **run-time precondition checks** at the start of the method.

```
public boolean doSomething(String param1, String param2) {
    if (!Objects.equals(param1, "String1") &&
        !Objects.equals(param1, "String2") &&
        !Objects.equals(param1, "String3"))
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("param1 must be String1, 2, or 3");
    }

    ...
}
```

Guava's [Preconditions class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) can be helpful.

```
public boolean doSomething(String param1, String param2) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(
        Objects.equals(param1, "String1") ||
        Objects.equals(param1, "String2") ||
        Objects.equals(param1, "String3"),
        "param1 must be String1, 2, or 3"
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an unit test that ensures that only some values are accepted by the method as param1 parameter at runtime.

Code a test with the two scenarios : valid and invalid cases.

For example in JUnit 5 :

```
@Test
public void doSomething(){ 
   Assert.AssertTrue(new Foo().doSomething("String1", "anyValue");
   Assert.AssertTrue(new Foo().doSomething("String2", "anyValue");
   Assert.AssertTrue(new Foo().doSomething("String3", "anyValue");
}

@Test
public void doSomething_with_illegal_argument(){ 
    Assert.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new Foo().doSomething("invalidValue", "anyValue"));
}
```

The test should fail as you actually don't guarantee that.
So then improve your actual implementation to make the test pass.

For example :

```
public boolean doSomething(String param1, String param2) {
    if (!"String1".equals(param1) &&
        !"String2".equals(param1) &&
        !"String3".equals(param1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("param1 should be ...");
    }
   ... // processing
}
```

I would add that a test unit cannot cover all failing cases if the failing cases are any `String` but 3 specific `String`s : it makes millions of possibilities.

In your case I think that the best way to make your code more robust is using a bounded type as an enum. You could so define a enum that contains 3 values and provide a enum constructor with the `String` actually passed as a parameter.

It could look like :

```
public boolean doSomething(MyEnum param1Enum, String param2){
   ...
   String param1 = param1Enum.getString();
}
```